# How to find two different data in single query - mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I was trying to get my followers post and its working properly.

```
  let followingUsersPost = await Post.find({ user: { $in: currentUser.following } })
    .populate('user', '_id name username')
    .sort({ createdAt: -1 });
```

But Now i also want to search my own posts, in same query (to get all data and merge it together)

**This is what i have tried,**
but its showing only my posts

```
  let followingUsersPost = await Post.find({ user: { $in: currentUser.following }, user: currentUser._id })
    .populate('user', '_id name username')
    .sort({ createdAt: -1 });
```

Comment: Either `$or` the two conditions together or append `currentUser._id` to the `currentUser.following` array and continue using `$in` with the new array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second `user` field in your query overwrites the first.
You can just merge following and current users ids. For example:

```
  let followingUsersPost = await Post.find({ user: { $in: [...currentUser.following, currentUser._id] } })
    .populate('user', '_id name username')
    .sort({ createdAt: -1 });
```

Comment: Thanks, I didnt know like we can use spread spread operator in mongoose query